# How to check if element is rendered in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to show a popup after table is completely loaded. Am using load property but it is not working. Is there any other way to achieve this? Without parent-child concept.

following is my code component.ts

```
export class FileUploadComponent {
    public files: UploadFile[] = [];
    data: AOA = [ [1, 2], [3, 4] ];
    wopts: XLSX.WritingOptions = { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'array' };
    fileName: string = 'SheetJS.xlsx';
    showData: boolean = false;

    public dropped(event: UploadEvent) {
       this.files = event.files;
       for (const droppedFile of event.files) {
         if (droppedFile.fileEntry.isFile) {
           const reader: FileReader = new FileReader();
           const fileEntry = droppedFile.fileEntry as FileSystemFileEntry;
           fileEntry.file((file: File) => {
              var filePath = file;
             reader.onload = (e: any) => {
              const bstr: string = e.target.result;
              const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.read(bstr, {type: 'binary'});
              const wsname: string = wb.SheetNames[0];
              const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet = wb.Sheets[wsname];
              this.data = <AOA>(XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws, {header: 1}));
            };
            reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
            this.showData = true;
            this.infoModal.hide();
          });
       } else {
          this.showData = false;
          const fileEntry = droppedFile.fileEntry as FileSystemDirectoryEntry;
       }
     }
   }

  showPopUp(){ 
     console.log('yes');
  }
}
```

Following is my component.htm

```
      <div class="modal-body">
        <file-drop id="infoFileModal" headertext="Drop files here" (onFileDrop)="dropped($event)" (onFileOver)="fileOver($event)" (onFileLeave)="fileLeave($event)"></file-drop>
      </div>

 <div class="card-body">
   <div *ngIf="showData" class="upload-table  table-responsive">
     <table #table class="table-bordered table-striped" id="dest_table" (load)="showPopup()">
        <tr *ngFor="let row of data">
           <td *ngFor="let val of row">
              {{val}}
           </td>
        </tr>
     </table>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="!showData" class="div-upload">
     No Data Found
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: does your table data come from service? or just static table?

Comment: Where do you get the table's content from? Do you fill the table by *ngFor?

Comment: You can use `ngAfterViewInit()` life cycle hook which is invoked when the component’s view has been fully initialized.

Comment: @ranjeet8082: In case of having a service that needs a lot of time to deliver the content this won't work properly.

Comment: @fatemefazli It does not come from service. I'm importing an excel file and displaying data. It is taking some time to render the table completely even after getting response.

Comment: @ranjeet8082 ngAfterViewInit() works only if table is loaded during page load. My table is not  displayed on page load

Comment: @Esco: You have to call your `showPopUp()` at the end of method you are importing your excel file with, in this case. As soon as the array is filled, the table will react and fill the cells within milliseconds.

Comment: @DiabolicWords it is not getting called that way. I tried it already. Hence the question

Comment: ok, what element is the last last element that shown in browser?a way is check till that element is exist.

Comment: @fatemefazli this table itself.. only then I have to perform rest operations -_-

Comment: @Esco: Please provide the code of your service. I need to see how you fetch your data and which services and methods are involved.

Comment: @DiabolicWords I've updated my code

Comment: @Esco: Please find my solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so here is another approach.

As your table takes several minutes for rendering, after the data-array has been filled, your only chance is to listen to the change-event as long as it takes. To prevent the showPopUp()-method from being fired with every finished iteration, you use Observable.debounceTime(), which only calls the method when the time past after the last change-event is greater than the given time in milliseconds.

Component

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, ViewChild, AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Subscription} from "rxjs/Subscription";

 @ViewChild('table') table: any;
 private timer= Observable.timer(1000); // wait one second before calling the method
 private subscription: Subscription;

 ngOnDestroy(): void {
    if(this.subscription){
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
 }

public dropped(event: UploadEvent) {
        // ...

        reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
        this.showData = true;
        this.infoModal.hide();

        // call the watcher with a delay of one second
        // in order to give angular enough time to build up the table
        this.subscription = this.timer.subscribe( () => {
            this.triggerTableWatcher();
        });

        // ...

}


triggerTableWatcher() {
    // define the object to listen to
    const trigger = this.table.changes();

    // define the debounce-time (adjust it, if it doesn't fit your needs)
    const debounceAt = trigger.debounceTime(1000);

    // subscribe to the trigger and tell which method to call eventually
    debounceAt.subscribe(() => this.showPopUp());
}
```

HTML-Template (only the important part of it)

```
<div class="card-body">
   <div *ngIf="showData" class="upload-table  table-responsive">
      <table #table class="table-bordered table-striped" id="dest_table">
         <tr *ngFor="let row of data">
              <td *ngFor="let val of row">
                {{val}}
             </td>
         </tr>
     </table>
</div>
```

Comment: @DiablolicWords am getting error as ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'changes' of undefined

Comment: @Esco Sorry mate. I've overlooked the fact, that you block the creation of your table by *ngIf as long as showData is false. That's why table is still undefined when AfterViewInit fires. I corrected, adjusted and extended my code. As your dropped()-method is so long, I only posted the most important part. Please copy & paste my code-fragment into your actual method beneath `this.showData = true;`. Please note, that I added a timer in order to give Angular the time to instantiate the table before you start monitoring it.  --  Please try again.

Comment: @DiablolicWords Thank you so much. That issue has been resolved with the above solution. Thank you so much for your time and patience. Thanks a ton :)

Answer (score 1):

Native table does not have any `load` event. This logic should be delegated to the service which loads the data.

Or, as suggested in the comment, you can use `ngAfterViewInit()`. 
But: If the table has been first rendered, and the you load data, then it will not work

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to the onloadend()-method of FileReader. Please look at the commented part of the code.

```
 public dropped(event: UploadEvent) {
     this.files = event.files;
     for (const droppedFile of event.files) {
       if (droppedFile.fileEntry.isFile) {
         const reader: FileReader = new FileReader();
         const fileEntry = droppedFile.fileEntry as FileSystemFileEntry;
         fileEntry.file((file: File) => {
            var filePath = file;
           reader.onload = (e: any) => {
            const bstr: string = e.target.result;
            const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.read(bstr, {type: 'binary'});
            const wsname: string = wb.SheetNames[0];
            const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet = wb.Sheets[wsname];
            this.data = <AOA>(XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws, {header: 1}));
          };
          reader.readAsBinaryString(file);

          // subscribe to the onloadend()-method here
          reader.onloadend = (e) => {
            this.showPopUp();
          };

          this.showData = true;
          this.infoModal.hide();
        });
     } else {
        this.showData = false;
        const fileEntry = droppedFile.fileEntry as FileSystemDirectoryEntry;
     }
   }
 }

 showPopUp(){ 
    console.log('yes');
 }
```

Comment: I tried your method, but even after load end it is still taking 1-2 minutes for table to render.